# Search through the Sessions Variable Array and update

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables

I am using this code to output all the registered session variables -

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_SESSION);
 echo "</pre>";
 exit();
```

This is what I get

```
Array
 (
[language] => english
[navigation] => navigationHistory Object
    (
        [path] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [get] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [post] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (

                        [get] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [post] => Array
                            (

                                [cart_number] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
                                [x] => 62

                            )
                )


            )

        )
 )
```

I would like to update the **cart_number** variable in the Session Array from XXXXXXXX... to 555555. I tried

```
$_SESSION['navigation']->path[1]['post']['cart_number'] = 5555555
```

This works and all but the problem is, the **cart_number** variable is not always in the 
[1] => Array. It can be in [2] or [3] or whatever.

So my question is, is there anyway I can may be search through the Session Array for that specific variable and update it with the right value? Thanks.

Comment: I am struggling to understand why you would do things this way.  If the cart number is an important value that you need to keep in session, why not just set it at `$_SESSION['cart_number']` whenever it needs to be updated.  Trying to go through a bunch of gyrations of parsing through your navigation history in order to change this value seems quite odd.

Comment: HI @MikeBrant, I am dealing with a Shopping cart which uses this logic to do everything, the array is quite longer than this, I stripped it just to make a point here. So to change how the function behaves is even more complicated and time demanding than just search and update. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set it this way..

```
foreach($_SESSION['navigation']->path as $key=>$val){
   if(isset($val['post']['cart_number'])) {
      $_SESSION['navigation']->path[$key]['post']['cart_number'] = 5555555;
   }
}
```

This will overwrite all cart_numbers which are set up

Answer (score 1):

The *simple* way would be to use `foreach` to loop over the `navigationHistory` objects until you found `['post']['cart_number']` (assuming there is just 1).

**Pseudo-code**

```
foreach ($_SESSION['navigation']->path as $navObj) {
    if (isset($navObj['post']['cart_number'])) {
        // update...
        break;
    }
}
```

A more OO approach could be a method that exists in `navigationHistory` to update `cart_number` or search the stack, like `find()`.

Comment: from the print_r which is provided I see only 1 navigationHistory object and a lot navigationHistory->path 's